# Rock, Paper, Scissors Bot

Tags: java, bots

My class is having a bot competition this week and we are supposed to make our bots to win over everyone elses bot. The competition is rock, paper, scissors, dynamite, water balloon. Dynamite beats everything except water balloon and water balloon only beats dynamite. The teacher wrote the battle arena, and some other bots, a smart bot, a printer(paper) bot, a random bot, and his bot to show us some examples.   I liked the smart bot and I used it to create mine and apparently I need to do more in my bot.  I am not sure what else to add and how to make my bot the one that wins.  I also need to keep track of how much dynamite I have.

My questions are as follows: what can I add to the bot to make it win and how do I keep track of the dynamite? 
Here is my bot:

```
public class herro1cb extends Bot {

public herro1cb(int dynamiteQuantity) {
    super(dynamiteQuantity);
    _dynamiteLeft = dynamiteQuantity;
    setName("Chelsea");
}

@Override
public Move doMove(Move opponentsPrior, int points) {


    switch( opponentsPrior ){
    case Dynamite:
        return _dynamiteLeft > 0 ? Move.Dynamite : Move.WaterBalloon;
    case WaterBalloon:
        return Move.Scissors;
    case Scissors:
        return Move.Rock;
    case Paper:
        return Move.Scissors;
    case Rock:
        return Move.Paper;
    default:
        return _dynamiteLeft > 0 ? Move.Rock : Move.Dynamite;
    }


}

}
```

Here is what is extended:

```
public abstract class Bot implements Comparable<Bot> {

private String _name;
protected int _dynamiteLeft = 0;

public Bot( int dynamiteQuantity ){
    _dynamiteLeft = dynamiteQuantity;
}


public String getName(){
    return this._name;
}
public void setName(String value){
    this._name = value;
}

public abstract Move doMove(Move opponentsPrior,int points);

public void reset(int dynamiteRenewal){
    _dynamiteLeft = dynamiteRenewal;
}


@Override
public int compareTo(Bot o) {
    return +Integer.compare( this.hashCode() , o.hashCode() );
}
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If everyone is trying to make a bot that "thinks further than the opponent", then you should try to keep a history of chosen moves. Try to find out how many iterations the other bot thinks ahead. Nothing prevents you of evaluating the whole history of moves every move you make.

By saying *thinks further than the opponent*, I mean something like:

> I just chose scissors, but the opponent chose rock, so he beat me. In
>   order to win, I should change to paper, but the opponent will know
>   that, and will pick scissors. In order to beat his "intelligent" move,
>   pick rock instead.

If other bots are based on this algo, you could beat them, if you could find out how many iterations they are thinking ahead.

I guess that you are unable to make something intelligent enough to beat a Randomized bot.

*Remark:* Your logic right now in the code basically beats the previous move of the opponent.

Comment: "I guess that you are unable to make something intelligent enough to beat a Randomized bot." How could anyone beat a randomized bot in traditional RPS? I realize this game has some non-random components (dynamite/water baloon), but is it possible to beat random-bot in RPS?

Comment: so youre saying play whatever their last move was. So if they do rock I do rock the next round and they play scissors and I play scissors?

Comment: @CBH: Depends on how many iterations you think ahead. You can continue that way of thinking.